# How to extract day like sun,mon etc from entered date(entered in dd/MM/yyyy) in neo4j 3.2.2

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi I'm kinda stuck with this small problem. I am working on a project in Neo4j 3.2.2 which requires me to extract the day(like Monday,Tuesday etc) out of the entered date in dd/MM/yyyy string format.
I've searched a lot on web for its solution but couldnt find one. I even checked previous stack overflow posts but couldnt find anything related to this so finally thought of posting it here. Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: What's your input format? Is it a timestamp or a string? Have you looked at GraphAware's Time Tree plugin? That will assist with a lot of the functionality you need. Day of the week should be straightforward to calculate on top of that.

Comment: @Dom thanks for replying, my input format is a string in dd/MM/yyyy format. I havent gone through GraphAware's Time Tree plugin but will go through it now.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood for a moment then! In cypher you can use the `split()` function to pull apart the different date components, and convert them into integers using `toInteger()`. From there you can work out the day of the week as an integer using one of the published methods on google!

Comment: You can take a look at APOC dates functions : https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_date_and_time_conversions

Answer (score 1):

There are many APOC [Date and Time](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_date_and_time_conversions) functions.

For example, this Cypher query:

```
RETURN apoc.date.fields('07/13/2017', 'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

returns this:

```
{"weekdays":4,"years":2017,"zoneid":"UTC","months":7,"days":13}
```

A "weekday" value of `4` represents "Thursday" (and a `7` would represent "Sunday"). The other fields should be self-explanatory.

Comment: @cybersam-thanks that really helped, but when i execute a query like "call apoc.date.fields('07/13/2017', ('MM/dd/yyyy')) yield value as line return line.weekday" it gives me an error stating There is no procedure with the name `apoc.date.fields` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed. could you please help me with this.

Comment: Did you install the APOC plugin ? You need to put https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/download/3.2.0.3/apoc-3.2.0.3-all.jar into the plugins folder of your installation, add dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.* into your neo4j.conf file and then restart the instance. Then you'll have the procedures and functions available.